Lombok builder() method returning null in Spring Boot application
I'm working on a Spring Boot application using JPA and Lombok. I have an Author entity with Lombok annotations. However, when I try to use the builder() method to create an Author object, IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition shows the builder() method in red and it returns null at runtime.
JpaApplication.java
package com.explorer.jpa;

import com.explorer.jpa.models.Author;
import com.explorer.jpa.repositories.AuthorRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(AuthorRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            var author = Author.builder()  // This line shows in red in IntelliJ, Exactly the .builder() part
                    .firstName("Johnny")
                    .lastName("Deep")
                    .age(35)
                    .email("contact@disney.com")
                    .build();

            repository.save(author);
        };
    }
}

Author.java
package com.explorer.jpa.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "firstname", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private int age;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(insertable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.explorer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot JPA</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Lombok Configuration:

Lombok plugin is installed and enabled in IntelliJ IDEA.
Annotation processing is enabled in IntelliJ settings.

Clean and Rebuild Project:

Ran mvn clean install.
Rebuilt the project in IntelliJ.

Verify Lombok Annotations:

Ensured the Author class has the correct Lombok annotations.

Checked Logs and Debugged:

No specific error messages related to Lombok or the builder() method in the logs.
Despite these steps, the issue persists. Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Details:

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Java Version: 17
Spring Boot Version: 3.3.1


Is there any errors after mvn clean install?

public Author (Integer id,String firstName,String lastName,String email, int 
age){
this.id = id;
this.firstName= firstName;
this.lastName= lastName;
this.email = email;
this.age = age;
}
// please add above constructor for your Entity    


well!. I tried it but failed again so i just reinstall the lombok plugin in Injelli IDEA now its works!!

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Author {

public Author (Integer id,String firstName,String lastName,String email, int 
age){
this.id = id;
this.firstName= firstName;
this.lastName= lastName;
this.email = email;
this.age = age;


}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "firstname", length = 50)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

private int age;

@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

@Column(insertable = false)
private LocalDateTime lastModified;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    lastModified = LocalDateTime.now();
  }
}
//Use above code .I add constructor with the parameter


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

well!. I tried it but failed again so i just reinstall the lombok plugin in Injelli IDEA now its works!!
